# Facebook Messenger crashing after update, persists after force stop and clearing data

Tags: facebook-messenger

I updated Facebook Messenger to the latest version (44.0.0.2.51) via the Google Play Store and now I keep getting the following message on my screen:

> Unfortunately, Messenger has stopped.

I get that message, even though I did a Force Stop and cleared data via the App Info settings. I then reached out to Facebook Android Beta and their answer for any issue is same:

> Try reinstalling the app and if you still experience the issue, report
>   it within the app. -Kevin

I'm not sure how reinstalling the app would solve coding issues, but just to be fair, I went ahead and reinstalled it anyways. Needless to say that did *NOT* solve anything and I cannot report the issue within the app as it keeps crashing and I can't even launch it.

Is there anything else I can do besides uninstall it?

Comment: If you've recently updated to Marshmallow, reinstall it again - it may need to ask for permissions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took following steps to resolve my issue:

- [How do I stop using the beta version of Messenger for Android? | Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/299954420152178)
- [How do I test the beta version of Messenger for Android? | Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/1414137108838897)

I followed first link and opt-out from beta tester, and then later that day I opt-in back as Facebook resolved issue that caused for Messenger to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it for now, I have also gotten this last week and again today.  It appears to be an update with the app that causes this.  I uninstalled it today as well because it was constantly popping up.

Comment: My bad, updating now...